# Laravel 10 install Breeze with Bootstrap 5?

Tags: php, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to ask for a little help.
Is there a way to install Breeze in Laravel 10 with the Bootstrap 5 framework instead of Taiwind?

Can you describe the steps?
Or do I just install and reformat the blades?
THANKS.

Comment: You can just install `laravel/ui`. https://github.com/laravel/ui

Comment: @xenooooo
laravel/ui is deprecated, look at github.com/laravel/ui first note in readme !

Comment: in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73026979/laravel-vite-config-using-separate-tailwind-config-files-for-admin-and-site you find https://github.com/pkfan/setup-laravel-vite-for-multiple-tailwind.config.js that could be help

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can do that.

- composer require laravel/breeze --dev
- php artisan breeze:install
- npm install bootstrap

and dont forget to add

- @import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
  in resources/sass/app.scss file
- npm run dev

Comment: you can uninstall the tailwind using 
- npm uninstall tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer
i really havenot used it i found it in web, do use it if didnt help please comment.

Comment: The goal of breeze is to add register/login/logout… logic and views. These views used tailwind so app.css contain `@tailwind base, conponent and utilities`, so remove tailwind require to change these views code… and what append at next update ? Probably the best way is to leave tailwind to breeze views and to add bootstrap to own views ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think removing tailwind from breeze is good to go, since breeze build for tailwind.

**step as follows :**

1. install breeze as usual

   `laravel new inertboosreact`
2. install boostrap

   `npm install bootstrap @popperjs/core sass`
3. at vite.config.js

   // input: 'resources/js/app.jsx',

   input: [
   'resources/sass/app.scss',
   'resources/js/app.jsx',
   ],
4. Add Sass folder at resources and add

   // Bootstrap

   @import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
5. to prevent boostrap clashing with tailwind, at tailwind.config.js add

   `prefix: 'tw-',`
6. replace all tailwind from breeze views with your own prefix class, simple copy paste it here, https://github.vue.tailwind-prefix.cbass.dev/

**check here, i have implement it all :**

**https://github.com/KingGeneral/base-breeze-boostrap-tailwind-laravel10**